# How does SQLite handle Massive Queries?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I'm developing an application and thinking of using SQLite.

My application will have to read (not write) massive ammounts of data, typically in the 4-5GB range.

So if one does the following:

```
SELECT * FROM MASSAVETABLE;
```

Would SQLite be able to process this large query? More specifically, is it able to manage the memory usage of the query? Most machines nowadays only have 4GB RAM.

Comment: Can't you just try it out? Note that code you've shown not going to read anything by itself - obtaining result would be, but it is not shown in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would load it all into your process' memory, correct.

Your OS would page memory in and out as necessary, but if this is a 32-bit process or on an embedded platform without page swapping then your program will crash with an out-of-memory error.

Do you really need everything in-memory?

Comment: Really? Why would SQLite read everything into memory at once?

Comment: @thilo because you asked it to :) SQLite does not (to my knowledge) have support for cursors and partial results. You'll have to implement some form of data paging in your schema by yourself.

Comment: @thilo apparently SQLite does support cursors, but you need to write your program to explicitly use them.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Cursor's are evil they say. I'll just manage it in code

Comment: @user1034912 cursors are not evil when used appropriately. Given SQLite is an in-proc system I see no problem using them.

Answer (score 3):

The database will not read the whole result set into memory at once. Your application has to be coded to avoid that, too. That's what cursors are for.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Cursor's are evil they say. I'll just code it then